# Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

I am trying to verify otp. The table in db for otp contains email and otp_no. I am getting the expected outcome if the otp provided by the user is correct but get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'email'" if the otp is wrong.

Following is the code:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def verifyOtp(request):
    email = request.data.get('email')
    otp_no = request.data.get('otp_no')
    res = dict()
    if email!= None and otp_no!= None:
        result = Otp.objects.filter(email=email, otp_no = otp_no).first()
        if len(result.email)> 0:
                res['isOtpVerified'] = True  if otp_no == result.otp_no else False
                return JsonResponse(res)
        else: 
            res['emailExist'] = False
            return JsonResponse(res)
```

what am I missing in the code?

Comment: You’re getting None queryset by that email and otp query. Try to figure out why it returns None. Else code is fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there are no entries in the database satisfying your filters. You are filtering `Otp.objects.filter(email=email, otp_no = otp_no).first()`. You are checking that email != None and otp_no != None (btw more clear way to do this is by writing `email is not None and otp_no is not None`). But even if they are not None user can pass the wrong email or wrong otp_no that are not exists in DB. Therefore you can have None value in your result variable, leading to that AttributeError.